# Is there a method of quickly determining whether a chunk read from a (sparse) file is all zeros?

Tags: c, file, d, sparse-file

Is there a method of quickly determining whether a (4KB-16MB) chunk read from a file is all zeros?

You can iterate over the chunk, checking each byte.  There are obvious optimisations, but it remains O(N).

My use case is for sparse files.  I would be perfectly happy for a partial solution, such that if the chunk I've just read is not backed by any disk storage (i.e. it is a hole) then return true.

Any hints?

Comment: I think this question is closer related to operating system APIs than any particular programming language.

Comment: If there is a a way, it's most likely (V)FS API specific.. so that would depend on OS and FS itself.

Comment: @David Linux (EXT3/4) and Windows (NTFS).  AFAIK OSX doesn't do sparse files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the operating system and sometimes the filesystem.  Linux since 2.6.28 has implemented the [`FIEMAP` `ioctl()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt), and ZFS on Solaris implements `SEEK_HOLE` and `SEEK_DATA` in `lseek()`.

Comment: FWIW, in the soon to be released 3.1 kernel, Linux also implements SEEK_HOLE/SEEK_DATA.

Comment: I don't suppose that will work on mmapped files too?  It would seem sensible.

Comment: @chrisdew: `FIEMAP` will work on the file descriptor if you have kept that open after creating the mmap.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was, "How does rsync do it?"

It turns out that rsync simply checks the data for blocks of zeroes, and writes them as sparse files.  See `fileio.c` in the rsync source code if you want the gory details.